# How to print the numbers bewteen a specific range in BST from highest to lowest with least nodes visited?

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

For a BST, I want to find the nodes' values in [a,b] form largerest value to smallest one. The simplest way I can think is as follows:

```
void printRange(BSTNode<Key,E>* root,int lowValue,int highValue) const
{
    if(root==NULL) return;

    printRange(root->right(),lowValue,highValue);
    if(root->key()>=lowValue&&root->key()<=highValue)
        cout<<root->key()<<" ";

    printRange(root->left(),lowValue,highValue);
}
```

But I want to know whether there is a way to print out these values with less nodes visited?

Comment: I indented your code. Please look if this is what you intended. When you format code, it's best to use four spaces for indentation on SO. Tabs or a mix of tabs and spaces usually mess up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are visiting all the nodes of the BST , irrespective of whether they lie in the range or not.
And printing only the required values.
A more refined algorithm would be :

1. Do inorder traversal of the BST.
2. Start from the root.
3. Process left subtree for inorder traversal only if the root of left subtree is smaller than 'lowValue'
4. Process right subtree only if root of right subtree is greater than 'highValue'
5. Else just return from the function.

   This way you do a filtered inorder traversal,visiting only the required part of your BST .

Comment: This answer is very wrong. The method you describes leaves out elements. Draw even the most basic AVL tree and you'll see why.

Comment: @AndrewGrant an example tree would be helpful to understand the bug, and improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question, is psuedo code, should have been this:

```
void printRange(int lower, int upper, BSTNode * node){
  if (node == NULL) return
  if (node->key <= upper) printRange(lower, upper, node->right);
  if (node->key >= lower && node->key <= upper) printf("%d",node->value);
  if (node->key >= lower) printRange(lower, upper, node->left);
}
```